# Android 10: 3-button navigation is obscuring bottom of the screen

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-10.0

I have had feedback from Pixel 3/4 users that the bottom of the screen on this app is cut off, obscuring buttons and possibly other controls that the user requires.

This has only started happening on Android 10. The app contains both Xamarin.Android axml and Xamarin.Forms xaml layouts for the views (the particular page that you are viewing below is Xamarin.Forms).

I don't want to set margins, paddings, gravity or such like on the entire app as obviously that would impact non Android 10/Pixel users. I don't really want to check the operating system version and programatically change those properties as that seems quite hacky and will quickly become unmanageable.

I've looked for something similar to a UseSafeArea property for navigation bars rather than notches but there doesn't seem to be any. Is using WindowInsets the only way to this or has someone else had/solved this issue?

How it looks (controls at bottom are obscured):

[image: Android 10/Pixel 4]

How it should look (and does on every other device, the data is different here but it's the view that matters):

[image: Android 9/Samsung S8]

Comment: did you try to use scrollview? And you said that UseSafeArea property, I just see it used in ios.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I solved by removing a few lines of code that were there to fix a bug that has since been fixed in Xamarin Forms.

It directly relates to this forum topic: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87176/windowsoftinputmode-doesnt-work-in-xamarin-forms-android

If these lines exist in your MainActivity.cs, try removing them and see if that works:

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize);
Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateHidden);
AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid.assistActivity(this);
```